# zClip is not working

Tags: jquery, zclip

This is Updated Code for Clip Copy

```
 <script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
```

in body section :

```
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="txtEmbedLink" />
    <button id="btnCopyClipboard">
        copy</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnCopyClipboard').zclip({
            path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy: $('#txtEmbedLink').val(),
            beforeCopy: function () {
                alert('before copy');
            },
            copy: function () {
                alert('copy');
                return $('#txtEmbedLink').val();
                            },
            afterCopy: function () {
                alert('after copy');
            }
        });
    });
```

the problem is when I click on button, just beforeCopy runs correctly, nothing after Copy, (guess the problem is Copy function: alert command in Copy runs correctly)

Comment: any error in your console?

Comment: the strange thing is 1)my button doesnt work after the first time I click on it, 2)nothing copied, even the function runs.I use firebug and it reachs to this point at the first time, but isnt working.

Comment: look at your firebug console, after u click the button, any error in your console? just weird that why u return false?

Comment: I'm sure its because of my few knowledge about web, I'm a juniour Dev :) , but just dont know why the page is postback someeimes when I clicked the button. so I returned false to prevent this.I edited the post so you can see my button generation code.

Comment: @Se0ng11 Something happens wrong. I change the copy code and add alert() to test if it enter to copy code,and it doesnt work.  I changed it like this :   copy: function () {
                    alert('enter to copt function');
                    return $("#<%=txtEmbedLink.ClientID%>").val();
                }

Comment: my mistake, did not see that return false is inside the button click, because the button type is submit, that why it will post back, which u do it correctly by adding return false

Comment: instead of putting the code in a button click, have you try to move the code to dom ready? As I had go through the sample in here, http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/, which the code show that it should reside in dom ready instead of button click

Comment: @Se0ng11 : I think the main problem is its cant enter to Copy: section. but dont know why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had found the solution for you, modify your code as the jsfiddle is different with the local code

attached with jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/sxeCM/101/

the main issue is the dynamic value that already mention in the web, and put it in dom ready instead of button click

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnCopyClipboard').zclip({
        path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf', //this remain as the one you had
        copy:function(){return $('#txtEmbedLink').val();} //change this to be the clientid
    });
});
```

**Updated answer:**

check this http://jsfiddle.net/sxeCM/102/

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnCopyClipboard').zclip({
            path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy:function(){return $('#txtEmbedLink').val();},
            beforeCopy: function () {
              console.log("test");
            },
            afterCopy: function () {
                alert('after copy');
            }
        });
    });
```

as tested in this jsfiddle, I figure out that alert in beforecopy eventually cause an unknow glitch where the zclip did not copy the text input, instead of using alert, I change it to console.log, which show that the copy work, so if you want to test, why don't replace your alert with `console.log("before copy")?` by the way, the path should remain as the original path you had, don't use the sample path

Comment: do you beleive its not WORK FOR ME??? in my system? is it possible if there is any special setting which disable copying? I exactly copyied the code into new project and ran it.

Comment: can the button be click? I need to troubleshoot for you step by step, have any red cross in your console?

Comment: yes, it Enter to function, and in copy:function... I insert an alert, it's executing . just dont copy. I added afterCopy function, and found out every function after copy is not working. I refer for js and swf file from the original location. but as the same, its not working.

Comment: Updated with latest findout and new jsfiddle

Comment: another new prob!  $('#btnCopyClipboard').zclip({ ... dont work when I clicked on the button!!!. in Fiddle it works .

Comment: what mean by not work? the path need to point to your project ZeroClipboard.swf

Comment: it works now, without any changes on that, just write a function for copy, but there is only one problem, the first time, its not work, when I clicked it again, it works once. the third time, it executes 3 times and .... :D .

Comment: I just execute CopyToClip twice, once in mouseOver(), and once in OnClick(). because it doesnt work on first click. thank you for helping all day and your giulds , I marked your answer as a right solution, as in your code, I shouldnt alert in beforeCopy. but just this last problem.

Comment: doesnt work on 1st click? update with your latest code and let me check, in jsfiddle it work fine, so there's should had some code conflict with it

Comment: I fixed it, but there is an strange error. why it works in my system, but it doesnt work in another system? the button is like a disable control which user cant click on it !!!!!????

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you solve it or not, I was looking for the reason for a long time, May it works for you too.

My problem is my attach Element is not ready. so the function "*is(:visible)*" alway "*false*", and the *width* and *offsetWidth* alway 0. you can try add setTimeout for the zclip attach.like

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('attchElement').zclip({
        path: 'ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: $('textarea').val()
    });
},500);
```